# Always WI-FI Timeout Error On MacOS

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking

I'm using MACOS X 10.7.5, this is my first time as a MacOS user.

I have just gotten a new MacBook and I have 2 problems with WI-FI.

I keep getting 'connection timeout' when i try to connect any WI-FI . I get this error when I click the network. However, when I wait enough time, it connects. In summary, it connects to WI-FI networks very well, but it keeps giving me timeout error. 
I read [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1201058), and you can see there are lots of people experiencing problems like this. But i couldn't find any solution.

Also it doesn't remember my WI-FI networks' passwords. I'm choosing 'remember this network' checkbox but it keeps asking me for password after every boot.

As I said this is a new MacBook. Could there be a problem with my computer's hardware? What should I do? Should I reinstall some drivers ?

Comment: Do you experience this problem only with your home network? Have you tried to connect to other WiFi like your work/school?

Comment: @Bichoy yes i've tried but have problem for all networks.

Answer (score 1):

Completely erase all information about your network excisting on you mac. This can be done with the following steps: First clear the lsit of preferred networks, found in System Preferences > Networks > Wifi > Advanced.

Now clear all the stored Wifi passwords in your keychain.
Start the Keychain access application, delete all the Airport network passwords stored in both Login and System.

After this Move SystemCOnfiguration folder found in /Library/Preferences/Systemconfiguration

Move the entire folder to your Desktop, after this make sure to delete it in the Preferences folder.

Now, shut down your mac and commence a SMC reset (just to be sure) explained here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964

after this commence teh NVram/PRam reset explained by Michel or here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379

Now when your mac has restarted and you are logged in, reconnect to your network to see if connection problems persist.

Answer (score 0):

- System Preferences / Network

In the left panel, use the Minus button to remove all the connections you have.

Reboot.

- System Preferences / Network

In the left panel, use the Plus button to add your Wifi network **first** !

Try to use your mac with just the Wifi setup for now, and be sure it is the first in the list if you have more than one item.

If this doesn't work, try to reset you NVRAM

> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard:
>      Command (⌘), Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down
>      simultaneously in step 4.
> 3. Turn on the computer.
> 4. Press and hold the
>      Command-Option-P-R keys before the gray screen appears.
> 5. Hold the keys
>      down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for
>      the second time.
> 6. Release the keys.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379

Comment: Will this delete my any  datas?